# How to setup SSH VPN in Network Manager?

Tags: 12.10, ssh, network-manager, vpn

I am using 12.10 and I want to setup SSH VPN via GUI in Network Manager,
But it has only pptp and no other types to select. How can I fix it? any packages I need to install?

Answer (score 7):

Full SSH VPN support for NetworkManager:

https://github.com/danfruehauf/NetworkManager-ssh

Should compile and package itself quite easily. If anyone wants to maintain it for ubuntu it'd be really sweet.

Comment: The README at that link also has a script that shows what the GUI accomplishes on the CLI. It may clear things up and shows why this is simpler than many other VPN options in certain environments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that you want to setup the server side of a VPN. You are looking at the client settings.

VPN can be tunneled through SSH, but it's not an ssh VPN.

Check out [OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN) And [Tunneling OpenVPN Through SSH](http://blog.redfern.me/tunneling-openvpn-through-ssh/).

You'll have to use command line.

Comment: No I mean when I want to add a vpn via connection manager, after clicking the add button, it will ask the vpn type. I can only see the pptp in the drop down list, I want to see the other types as well, it also say if you had the required packages, it will show the other types ( more than pptp )

Comment: But you don't know which type? L2TP or openvpn? What server are you connecting to?

Comment: He's connecting to an SSH server using an SSH client over a tunnel. These are all features OpenSSH provides built in. If you have SSH access and they haven't turned off the ability to make tunnels for your account, you can make your own VPN access.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for a CISCO compatible solution. When you

```
apt-cache search cisco vpn
```

you should see `openconnect` and the `network-manager-openconnect` which worked for me as clients. The command line tool is `vpnc` which also works but that's a question of taste I guess. Try

```
sudo apt-get install openconnect network-manager-openconnect
```

and go back to the drop down menu.

Comment: the OP asked about ssh tunnel type VPN not a CISCO compatible solution